# error in using casl for role based permission

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, casl

This is how I have defined ability using **casl**

ability.js

```
import { AbilityBuilder } from '@casl/ability';
//   case 'Administrator':
// localStorage.getItem('role')
export default function() {
 AbilityBuilder.define(can => {
    switch(localStorage.getItem('role')) {
      case 'Admin':
      case 'CEO':
        can(['add', 'read','update', 'delete']);
        break;
     case 'Manager':
        can(['add', 'read','update', 'delete']);
        break;
     case 'Senior':
        can(['add', 'read']);
        break;
     case 'Clerk':
     case 'Administrator':
       can('read');
       break;  
    }
  })
}
```

I have registered in main.js

```
import { abilitiesPlugin } from '@casl/vue';
import ability from './config/ability';

Vue.use(abilitiesPlugin, ability);
```

Now I wanted to use it in the component:

```
<v-icon
   v-if="$can('delete')"
   small
   class="mr-2"
   @click="editItem(item)"
   >
   edit
</v-icon>
```

This is giving me error :  `Error in render: "TypeError: t.on is not a function"`. I have implemented this using few resources online. So the error says that the can is not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You return a function from `config/ability` but `Vue.use` expects to receive an `Ability` instance.

The error says that something trying to access `on` property on the `t`, where `t` is an argument of `abilitiesPlugin` function from `@casl/vue`.

So, replace the line `Vue.use(abilitiesPlugin, ability);` with `Vue.use(abilitiesPlugin, ability());` in main.js . This should fix the error.

**P.S.**: make sure to use the latest version. `AbilityBuilder.define` is removed from CASL v4